# What could be the reason that CyclicBarrier.await() function generates a Null pointer Exception

Tags: java, cyclicbarrier

I am using the CyclicBarrier class , await() to synchronize the different threads which process different documents simultaneously. However this function seems to return a Null pointer exception in most inputs of documents. Could someone help me out to avoid this exception?

Comment: Can you paste your code?

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason this method should ever throw a NullPointerException, if you didn't use the version with a timeout and gave `null` as a time unit.

Are you sure the NullPointerException comes from this method? Have a look at the stack trace (or paste it into the question, if you can't interpret it).